# Univariate probability distribution over tuples

Tags: statistics, tuples

I would like to generalize an existing univariate probability distribution framework to the analysis of 3-tuples.

In the existing framework, normal or beta distributions, respectively, are fitted to a distribution over real numbers. Now I would like to use a similar approach on tuples of at least 3 real numbers. I guess I should switch to the multivariate versions of these distributions; however, another naive idea was to map the tuples to the set of real numbers like in Cantor Pairing.

What would be the best approach? I am afraid that for the future the requirements could extend to k-tuples with k > 3.

Which R-packages provide Cantor Pairing?

Best regards

Comment: you can use a univariate PDF (probability density function) as multivariate PDF provided the tuples have independent parts, so the tuple PDF is just the product of each univariate PDF. However if the tuples are inter-depednent you will need a multivariate PDF from the start

Comment: **note** you can map each tuple to a single number but the PDF of that will be quite different from the PDF of a tuple item, there will be correlations and inter-dependencies so the final PDF can be quite different (not even a gaussian)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would like to model the course of a time series fragment by means of the tuples; e.g. the numbers of time points with (increasing, decreasing, constant) values. I guess these characteristics ARE NOT independent (the higher the number of constant values, the lower the others); however, I could use these dependencies to bring the tuple size k down to two, for example.

Comment: The multivariate version of the beta distribution is called the Dirichlet distribution. Hope this helps.